# "No such file or directory exists"?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, putty

Ok, so I have this Virtual Dedicated Server laying around, and I thought I'd turn it into a game server. So, I used wget in PuTTy to download the Half-Life Game server installer package, but when I go to run it, it says "No such file or directory exists". But, when I list the files in the directory, it shows up, so it's there, but it's not recognizing it for some reason. What's causing this?

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information so that we can help you. What Operating System are you running? Have you checked the error logs in /var/log? What do you do when you try to "run the installer package" (what commands are you running, what type of file is it, etc...)? Also, not trying to be a jerk, but this question could very well be considered off topic, per the FAQ (http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

You'll see this happen when the binary is a different architecture than the system you're running.

Execute these commands:

```
uname -m
```

(Probably reports `x86_64`)

and

```
file <half-life-game-server>
```

(Probably reports `ELF 32-bit LSB executable`)

Is it the same architecture?

In order to run 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system you need the 32-bit glibc runtime. For Debian/Ubuntu install the `libc6-i386` package.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% certain that your problem is that you didn't download the file to a location in `$PATH`.  Unlike on Windows, most Unixes don't consider the current directory to be in the path by default.

You need to move the file to a directory in `$PATH` (for instance, `/usr/local/bin` is probably in it) or give the path to the executable when you run it, for instance `./install.sh`.

The remaining 1% is forgetting to use `chmod` to mark the file executable after downloading it.